# how can i render table with their associated project in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

i have created scaffold project and stage in rails. both have many to one association in rails. like each project will have multiple stage and user will have multiple project. i am able to render project will associated user id but stage gets rendered on every user. i can i resolve this?

project.rb

```
  has_many :stages
```

stage.rb

```
  belongs_to :project
```

project show.html.erb where i render stage of project

```
<div class="table-scroll">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Stage</th>
        <th>Responsibility</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Finance</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% @stages.each do |stage| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= stage.stage %></td>
          <td><%= stage.responsibility %></td>
          <% if stage.status == true %>
            <td class="completed"><%= "Completed" %></td>
          <% elsif stage.status == false %>
            <td class="in-progress"><%= "In-Progress" %></td>
          <% else %>
            <td class="yet-to-start"><%= "Yet to Start" %></td>
          <% end %>
          <td><%= stage.finance %></td>

        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

projects_controller.rb

```
def index
    @projects = current_user.projects.all.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
  end

  def show
    @project=Project.find(params[:id])
    @stages = Stage.all
  end

  def new
    @project = current_user.projects.build
  end

  def create
    @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

stages_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @stages = Stage.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @stage = Stage.new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  end


  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @stage = @project.stages.build(stage_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @stage.save
        format.html { redirect_to project_stages_path, notice: 'Stage was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @stage }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @stage.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

i want stage to be render only to their associated project. what changes i need to do?

Comment: On a side note - don't use a boolean for a status. Its a horrible db design choice. A string or an integer or anything else or even multiple boolean columns are better choices. Especially since you seem to be using a null state which means that its not even really a boolean.

Comment: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/avoid-the-threestate-boolean-problem

Comment: @max thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def show
  @project = Project.includes(:stages).find(params[:id])
  @stages = @project.stages
end
```